# Converting an HLS (m3u8) to MP4

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, http-live-streaming, transcoding

Can anyone advise on how to construct an `MP4` file from an `HLS` stream (the reverse of what you usually want)? Say I have the m3u8 - is there a straightforward way of getting a single `MP4` using `FFMPEG` or some other tool?

Comment: `ffmpeg -i in.m3u8 -acodec copy -vcodec copy out.mp4`

Comment: @szatmary I think it also needs `-bsf:a aac_adtstoasc`

Comment: @aergistal for aac audio yes, for mp3 audio no.

Comment: @szatmary of course, but I think AAC in HLS is pretty common

Comment: @aergistal as is MP3. and DD+

Answer (score 61, accepted):

`ffmpeg -i in.m3u8 -acodec copy -vcodec copy out.mp4`

For AAC audio you will also need to add the the bit ststream filter. (Thanks @aergistal for pointing that out)

`ffmpeg -i in.m3u8 -acodec copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -vcodec copy out.mp4`

Comment: Would this command generate an MP4 file with all the alternate audio tracks and side-car VTT captions from the HLS to burn in captions and audio tracks within the MP4?

Answer (score 4):

An alternative way of converting an HLS to MP4 is using VLC Player. You can do the conversion through the interface as well as commandline. Simply you can run a `.bat` file which has following lines:

```
chcp 65001
"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" http://cdn.haramain.global/vods3/_definst_/mp4:amazons3/akra/programlar/yeni/335/c07f21e3-a313-4e8d-b594-403ddefbf11f.mp4/playlist.m3u8 --sout "#transcode{vcodec=none,acodec=mp3,ab=70,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:std{access=file{no-overwrite},mux=mp3,dst='C:\Users\aidata\Desktop\Akra FM\13.07.2013 - Karagöz - Bilmecesi.mp3'}" vlc://quit
"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" http://cdn.haramain.global/vods3/_definst_/mp4:amazons3/akra/programlar/yeni/335/dcb6754a-49f1-4517-bfe4-3864942f63c8.mp4/playlist.m3u8 --sout "#transcode{vcodec=none,acodec=mp3,ab=70,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:std{access=file{no-overwrite},mux=mp3,dst='C:\Users\aidata\Desktop\Akra FM\12.07.2013 - Nasreddin Hoca - Köyün Eseği.mp3'}" vlc://quit
```

This batch script converts two files one after another. If you had pasted these commands into cmd.exe, all conversions would start at the same time.

---

Now let me explain the codes. The `chcp 65001` line allows you to use unicode characters in the destination file name. Following lines consist of four parts.

1. `"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe"`

This is the path of the VLC player. Verify this after installing VLC player.

2. `http://cdn.haramain.global/vods3/_definst_/mp4:amazons3/akra/programlar/yeni/335/c07f21e3-a313-4e8d-b594-403ddefbf11f.mp4/playlist.m3u8`

This is a sample HLS file. I don't know what happens if you put this link in double quotes.

3. `--sout "#transcode{vcodec=none,acodec=mp3,ab=70,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:std{access=file{no-overwrite},mux=mp3,dst='C:\Users\aidata\Desktop\Akra FM\13.07.2013 - Karagöz - Bilmecesi.mp3'}"`

This is the VLC command for conversion. You can find more options in [VLC Documentation](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Command_Line_Examples/)

4. `vlc://quit`

This will close the VLC window. It is helpful if you don't want your taskbar to be filled with VLC windows. There is no way to stack conversion orders in playlist. You have to run VLC, do the conversion and close the window. You can also try running VLC in silent mode. Or you can drag a VLC window to right bottom of your screen so that subsquent flashing windows won't disturb you.